# How can I prove that these two statements relating to a measurable function are equivalent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma)$, $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be the two measurable space. Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function. Then the following statements are equivalent:

(1) $f^{-1}(A)=\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\in A\}\in \Sigma, \forall A\in \mathcal{B}$.

(2) $\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\in (-\infty, x]\}\in \Sigma,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I don't have a clue about how the above two statements are equivalent. Would anyone care to shed some light on it?

Comment: You have to show that the intervals of the form $(-\infty, x]$ generate the Borel sigma-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I suppose that $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma -$algebra. The implication $(1)\implies (2)$ is clear. For the converse, let $\mathcal A:=\{B\mid f^{-1}(B)\in \Sigma\}$. It's a $\sigma -$algebra that contains all sets of the form $(-\infty ,x]$. Therefore $$\mathcal B=\sigma \{(-\infty ,x]\mid x\in \mathbb R\}\subset \mathcal A.$$

Comment: I am still not able to comprehend how can you prove (1) from (2)?

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's for $(2)\implies (1)$ that you don't understand. Do you agree that $(-\infty ,x]\in \mathcal A$ for all $x$ and that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma -$algebra ? @RobinKurtz

Comment: How is $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma-$ algebra?

Comment: @RobinKurtz: As I wrote, it's a hint... so, this is your job to prove it ;-)

Comment: Ok, but what is set $B$ and how $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: As written in my answer (and as I guess from your OP), $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma -$algebra. The fact that $\mathcal B\subset \mathcal A$ comes from the fact that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma -$algebra that contains the set $\{(-\infty ,x]\mid x\in \mathbb R\}$, and thus $$\mathcal B=\sigma \{(-\infty ,x]\mid x\in \mathbb R\}\subset \mathcal A.$$ @RobinKurtz

Comment: I still have no clue about how the $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I got what you were saying.